# Use of Enums in Angular 8 HTML template for *ngIf

Tags: html, angular, typescript, enums

How can I use Enums in the Angular 8 template?

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeEnum } from './global';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = SomeEnum.someValue;
}
```

component.html

```
<span *ngIf="name === SomeEnum.someValue">This has some value</value>
```

This currently doesn't work, since the template has no reference to `SomeEnum`. How can I solve it?

`ERROR Error: Cannot read property 'someValue' of undefined`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: ERROR Error: Cannot read property 'someValue' of undefined

Comment: have you tried creating a `public get SomeEnum() {return SomeEnum; }` in the TS and then in the HTML use `ngIf="SomeEnum.someValue"`

Comment: For future reference, there is already an open feature request in the offical repo: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33652

Answer (score 155, accepted):

in the TS

```
import { SomeEnum } from 'path-to-file';

public get SomeEnum() {
  return SomeEnum; 
}
```

in the HTML use

```
*ngIf="SomeEnum.someValue === 'abc'"
```

---

EDIT:
Time goes by and we learn more as a developer, the approach I'm using right now doesn't use the `get` method.
Both solutions work, just choose the one you like the most.

in the TS

```
import { SomeEnum } from 'path-to-file';

export class ClassName {
  readonly SomeEnum = SomeEnum;
}
```

in the HTML use

```
*ngIf="SomeEnum.someValue === 'abc'"
```

Comment: Wow, this is probably the more cleaner way to do it. Like your answer.

Comment: It's not recommended to use `get`ters though. They cost a lot of performance. So the `get`ter function runs every time Angular performs Change Detection. Now, I'm not saying that just running this function will cost performance. But then this leaves room for someone to add some logic in this `get`ter which might result in performance hits. Just saying. 

Comment: @SiddAjmera I don't know about this performance issue, can you please show us a source for searching about that? I use this for Enums because they look cleaner in the code. Thanks!

Comment: Ummmm. Well. Just place a console.log in the `get`ter and place an input in your template with an `[(ngModel)]` Or just run [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgjqo8?file=src/app/app.component.html) and see the console :)

Comment: This is triggered by the `ngIf`, not the getter itself. `ngIf` looks in the variables aswell, but you just can't console them hahaha.

Comment: Yeah but the bottom-line here is, that it's a data-binding syntax. You'll see that happening if you use it in a string-interpolation / property-binding / event-binding syntax.

Comment: All those solutions are not 100% clean and this is probably something that is worth to make a feature request for that as it currently does not have a real native solution for that.

Comment: For future reference, there is already an open feature request in the offical repo: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33652

Answer (score 33):

You'll have to declare it as a property first:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeEnum } from './global';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = SomeEnum.someValue;
  importedSomeEnum = SomeEnum;
}
```

And then use it in the template:

```
<span *ngIf="name === importedSomeEnum.someValue">This has some value</span>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpw8pe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 17):

I think this would be one of the simpler solutions if you do not want to bloat your class with unnecessary logic. I would avoid calling a function to return the enum because it will be called on every re-render and will impact your performance if this is heavily used.

```
public readonly myEnum : typeof MyEnum = MyEnum;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can declare a field equal to the `SomeEnum` enum (it may be imported from another file) as a public class field in the component file. Then it will be accessible in the template.

```
// component 
export class AppComponent  {
  name = SomeEnum.someValue;
  enum = SomeEnum;
}

// template
<span *ngIf="name === enum.someValue">This has some value</value>
```

Comment: If the enum is usable elsewhere, it would be better to have it in a separate file. And then simply importing it in the component as property.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. You don't have to declare the enum in the same file as the component. I've edited my answer.

Comment: However, with StrictTemplating this way gets flagged. If you know a way around, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the template cannot refer to the enum directly.
There are few ways to do this.
1. Add Enum reference to the component ts file like below

```
someEnum = SomeEnum;
```

then you will be able to use the reference in your template like this

```
<span *ngIf="name === someEnum.someValue">This has some value</value>
```

2. The second way is to call a function from your template with name as parameter and compare it in the typescript file

`<span *ngIf="checkCondition(name)">This has some value</value>`

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use this enum in many components, I suggest you use a Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeEnum } from 'path/to/some-enum.enum';

@Pipe({
    name: 'compareToSomeEnum',
})
export class CompareToSomeEnumPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(
        value: SomeEnum,
        compareTo: keyof SomeEnum,
    ): boolean {
        return value === SomeEnum[compareTo];
    }
}
```

And then use it in any template like this:

```
<span *ngIf="name | compareToSomeEnum : 'someValue'">This has some value</span>
```

I hope this helps!