# How can I make an enum appear in my Angular Mat-Form-Field?

Tags: java, angular, enums, mat-form-field

This is my app - [My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ielbC.png)
How can I write in Java/Visual Studio that in my app when I click on "Upgrade" for the id 1, the "Account" row, to appear CASH - the default value? For now it doesn't appear any value.

I make this enum in Java:

```
public enum Account {
    CASH{
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Cash";
        }
    },
    CARD{
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Card";
        }
    },
}
```

And this field form in Visual Studio :

```
 <mat-form-field appearance= "fill" style="margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px">
            <mat-label>Account</mat-label>
            <mat-select>
              <mat-option value="account" type= "text" formControlName="account">CASH</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="account" type= "text" formControlName="account">CARD</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of Enums in Angular 8 HTML template for \*ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289095/use-of-enums-in-angular-8-html-template-for-ngif)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650790/set-default-option-in-mat-select/50651134#50651134

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-working-enums

Answer (score 0):

check https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples#select-initial-value. You need to use a default `[(value)]` in your `mat-select` attribute. Example explain this very well. Good luck!